# Is it cheap to create brand new HttpClient per request

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient

I always thought it's an antipattern since MS docs [was always saying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#examples) "`HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use". But the more I dive into modern C# development the more I see things changed. For example here is [a tweet](https://twitter.com/jamesnk/status/988340452372889600) about `IHttpClientFactory`

> A new HttpClient is created each time, but HttpClient is cheap to
>   create.
>
> The internal HTTP handler that the HttpClient uses to make the request
>   (i.e. the part that does all the work and is expensive) is
>   intelligently cached and reused by the factory.

Which says if you reuse `HttpMessageHandler` for multiple `HttpClient`s you're golden.

Assume we want to set some headers for each HTTP request. Should we do it the old fashion way with `HttpRequestMessage` interceptors or could I just create a per-request `HttpClient` and since I'm going to reuse the same `HttpRequestMessage` I'm completely fine? Is it the modern way to perform per-request message modifications?

Comment: As far as I know these little HttpClients don't get disposed, see https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/ee7abfa96b484b6dbe26fb5c3979998318ab9599/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L63

Comment: @emilsteen That was written before IHttpClientFactory was released in 2.1, it isn't really relevant anymore unless you're on version <= 2.0

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy This should explain it better. https://dev.to/xhantimda/introducing-the-httpclientfactory-3ege

Comment: You need a unique response for each request.  Not sure if you really need a new request.  Why do you need to change the request after you gone through all the code to set the parameters.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I was answering a guy above me but he deleted his comment so I looked like I said things loud... Anyway, thanks for clarification. I need to redo my habits this way. I know lots of developers who still think HttpClient is really expensive. Anyone mind making an answer so I mark it?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpRequestMessage` is not intended to be reused. `HttpClient` will actually modify the `HttpRequestMessage` when sending your request, so it's not a good idea to use it afterward.

In general, use `IHttpClientFactory`. It does more than just reusing a message handler, such as periodic recycling of connection pools.

One good use of creating multiple `HttpClient` instances against a single message handler is if you want to set different default headers for calling multiple APIs against the same endpoint. This allows for pooling of connections to that endpoint without needing to set headers on each message.